# How do I get a live stream of deltas from Meteor collection, for use outside of a webapp?

Tags: node.js, meteor

How do I get a live stream of deltas from Meteor collection, for use outside of a webapp?

I'm looking for an initial result set, plus a series of operations on that result set, delivered as the happen.

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Meteor protocol is called DDP. It does exactly what you're asking for: you send a "subscribe" message that says what data you want to get, and then you get back the initial result set and then a stream of create/update/delete messages.

So what you need is a DDP client for whatever language the other program is written in. Since Meteor is so new, these don't exist yet. But a lot of people already written in to say that they want to write them. If you're interested in getting involved with that you should send a message to contact@meteor.com.

Answer (score 7):

They just added a small [python command-line tool](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/unfinished/python-ddp-client) for talking to a Meteor DDP server.

Answer (score 1):

Geoff is right, but as I searched for the same solution I just found two working with Javascript

- depends on jQuery https://github.com/eddflrs/meteor-ddp (recommended)
- a light standalone solution https://github.com/bmcmahen/ddp-sockjs-client

hopefully both are working with the specifications for ddp https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md

Comment: And now I just added oauth support to meteor-ddp https://github.com/eddflrs/meteor-ddp/pull/2