# how can meteor be coupled to an android app?

Tags: android, meteor

The meteor homepage (www.meteor.com) says in bullet point 8 ("interoperability"):

> You can connect anything to Meteor, from native mobile apps to legacy
>   databases to Arduinos. Just implement the simple DDP protocol.

Question: Android is Java, how can it connect to meteor (js)? Any links to useful resources / tutorials would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's an up-to-date Android client that works with the latest versions of Meteor: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI, I wrote up a higher level Android DDP layer that takes care of client state including collection handling.

It's on github and includes Maven artifacts in Maven Central (my version of the java-ddp-client also is in Maven Central):
  https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client

Comment: Hi, trying to run the MeteorPartiesDDPClient example. But it does not work . It is not able to connect to the server. The error is "websocket initialisation error. (Exception in callback?)".

Answer (score 5):

DDP stands for *Distributed Data Protocol* and is specific for Meteor.

There is no built-in Android/Java support yet, but here is an official Meteor DDP client written in Python that you could use as a reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/unfinished/python-ddp-client

More information:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128430/documentation-or-code-details-on-meteors-ddp-pub-sub-protocol
- [How do I get a live stream of deltas from Meteor collection, for use outside of a webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102869/how-do-i-get-a-live-stream-of-deltas-from-meteor-collection-for-use-outside-of/)

Comment: There is a [C# DPP Client](https://github.com/sonyarouje/DDPClient.NET/blob/master/Net.DDP.Client/DDPClient.cs) on GitHub, described in [DDPClient.NET– .NET Client For The Meteor Distributed Data Protocol](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/ddpclientnet%E2%80%93-net-client) which might be a useful start point for anyone writing an Android or general Java client.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why no one mentioned this, but there is a Java DDP client library:

https://github.com/kutrumbo/java-ddp-client

FYI, I've forked this and fleshed it out quite a bit.  I started writing an Android app with it and found it missing a lot of stuff to get it to work properly:

https://github.com/kenyee/java-ddp-client

I also wrote up an Android layer over this to make things easier and will check it into Github as soon as I figure out how to get it to work w/ Gradle in Eclipse (can't get it to recognize the android-libraries plugin so none of the references to the Android library work)-:
I did write an Android app using all this stuff...look in the Play store for "Meteor.js Party" which matches Meteor's Parties sample.

Comment: Are there any plans to get the library up to speed with `Meteor 1.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Clients can communicate with Meteor through its [DDP protocol](https://www.meteor.com/ddp) ([specs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md)). Look at the [list of independent DDP implementations](http://meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients) for common platforms.