# How to make a post request to a meteor server from android application

Tags: android, node.js, http-post, meteor

I am making an android application in which I want to post some data to a web server for a chat service. I am thinking of using `meteor` which is based on `node.js` for the back end as well front end. How do I make a post request to node server in a meteor application from my android device?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is really what you want to do for a *chat* application?

Don't forget Meteor handles bi-directional communications between the client and server for you.

It's much more likely that you want to simply add the chat text to the database with a Collection insert call, with a Meteor Method call, or look also at Arunoda's [meteor-streams](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-streams#documentation) smart package.

All 3 options will work faster and be easier to code, than relying on POST requests (don't forget, by default Meteor leverages an open WebSocket connection, when available).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Kinslayer. You are right, ultimately I want to add some chat text to the mongodb table. But can I make a Collection insert call from my native android app If yes then how? I want to update the database from my android app. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I missed your reply somehow.  The "correct" way to do this is with an Android DDP library.  It looks like this has come up before, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581948/how-can-meteor-be-coupled-to-an-android-app

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned if you are doing native android or using [`cordova`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/) for android. If you are using cordova the you can make http calls by Meteor's http API. [See docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http).

Sample POST request using meteor, you have to import `http` package as `meteor add http`:

```
Meteor.http.call("POST", 
                 "http://your.serverurl.com/path",
                 {data: {some: "json", stuff: 1}},
                 function (error, result) {
                   if (result.statusCode === 200) {
                     //do something
                   }
                 });
```

Or if you are doing native android app. you can do this by Java `HttpPost` class. See [this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/)

Comment: I am making a native android application. But I want to make an http post request to my meteor server. How can I use the `Meteor http package` from inside my android app? The server code sits in some javascript file or probably inside an html document. How do I send data to that server to update the database?